# Javascript arrays returning equal as long as first element is equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I am trying to compare two javascript arrays of integers up to the length of one array. Meaning, that I have one array that builds with user input and a goal array the user is trying to reach, and I just want to make sure the user has input the correct sequence up to the point that the user has input.

e.g.

If the goal array is [0, 3, 5, 4] and the user has input [0, 3, 5] so far I want my method to return true. My attempt in doing this is:

```
function compareArrays(){
    for(var i=0; i<playerPattern.length; i++){
        if (playerPattern[i] !== pattern[i]){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

this is called everytime the event handler picks up user input:

```
    if(isInButton(greenButton, mouseX, mouseY)){
        playerPattern[playerPattern.length] = 0;
        console.log(pattern);
        console.log(playerPattern);
        console.log(compareArrays());
        if(compareArrays() === false){
            youLose();
        } else if(compareArrays() === true && playerPattern.length === pattern.length){
            clickTile(0);
            score++;
            playerPattern.length = 0; //reset the playerPattern array because they completed the turn
            setTimeout(increasePattern, 1000);
        } else {
            clickTile(0);
        }
    } else if(isInButton(redButton, mouseX, mouseY)){
 ...
 ...
```

I don't see why this method would return true as long as the first element in the user array is true.

e.g. The method returns true in the case of goal: [0, 3, 4, 5] and user [0, 2, 1, 0]

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have `return` statements in both branches of the `if`, your function always stops immediately after comparing the first elements.

The `return true` statement should be *outside* the loop:

```
function compareArrays(){
    for(var i=0; i<playerPattern.length; i++){
        if (playerPattern[i] !== pattern[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: oh jeez, it has been a long night. well thanks for catching that for me.